# How to get current day of month properly in Tizen c program

Tags: c, tizen, tizen-wearable-sdk

the following program works with c compiler and returns correct date. But on tizen app code it returns 0:

```
time_t my_time;
    struct tm * timeinfo;
    time (&my_time);
    timeinfo = localtime (&my_time);

    int y = timeinfo->tm_year+1900;
    int m = timeinfo->tm_mon+1;
    int d = timeinfo->tm_mday;
 char day[10];

dlog_print(DLOG_DEBUG, "GG", "Current time: %d %d %d", y,m,d);
```

required screenshot:

[image]

it shows 0 only for date(d) but other m and y is printed correctly. Also similar code prints correct date on other c complier program.

How to get current day of the month properly?

Answer (score 0):

You can use **[Watch Application API](https://developer.tizen.org/development/api-references/native-application?redirect=https://developer.tizen.org/dev-guide/5.0.0/org.tizen.native.wearable.apireference/group__CAPI__WATCH__APP__MODULE.html)** on the wearable profile.

You can also find sample code in **Tizen Studio sample application(Classic Watch)** like as below.

```
/**
 * @brief Called at each second. This callback is not called while the app is paused or the device is in ambient mode.
 * @param[in] watch_time The watch time handle. watch_time will not be available after returning this callback. It will be freed by the framework.
 * @param[in] user_data The user data to be passed to the callback functions
 */
void app_time_tick(watch_time_h watch_time, void* user_data)
{
    int hour = 0;
    int min = 0;
    int sec = 0;
    int year = 0;
    int month = 0;
    int day = 0;
    int day_of_week = 0;

    watch_time_get_hour(watch_time, &hour);
    watch_time_get_minute(watch_time, &min);
    watch_time_get_second(watch_time, &sec);
    watch_time_get_day(watch_time, &day);
    watch_time_get_month(watch_time, &month);
    watch_time_get_year(watch_time, &year);
    watch_time_get_day_of_week(watch_time, &day_of_week);

    _set_time(hour, min, sec);
    _set_date(day, month, day_of_week);
    _set_moonphase(day, month, year);
}
```

Comment: My watch examples were not working/updating time until I added them as watch face :( . So, I assume, In order to work with this method the app has to be a watch face and set as watch face or this CB function will not be called.

This solution returns 0 for apps. and this solution is not appropriate for other instances.